# Alerting User to pauses in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a very long batch script that could run for hours, and for various purposes I have included a way for users if they would like a pause in the script in case of errors, the need to use the machine for something else, or in case they cannot watch it all the time. I've been using PAUSE to wait on input, but I'd like to have some sort of way for the user to be explicitly told that the batch is stopped, like a flashing icon on the taskbar or something.

Is there a simple way to do this or does it require more than a few lines of code?

Comment: Edit your post and add your code ! or some of your code !

Comment: Stephan and MC ND provided the bits similar to what I was looking for. They will work in combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
msg console /time:3600 "The batch file is waiting for input" & pause
```

Answer (score 2):

quite simple, as long as the windows stays open:

```
color c7&pause&color
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood you, the Batch file must alert the user (that may be distant from the computer) when it require attention. Try this:

```
:loop
   color E4
   choice /C NY /N /T 1 /D N /M "To end flashing, press Y"
   if errorlevel 2 goto exitLoop
   color
   choice /C NY /N /T 1 /D N /M "To end flashing, press Y"
if not errorlevel 2 goto loop
:exitLoop
color
```

Comment: Sort of what I was looking for. I did some more searching and found that to get the actual icon on the taskbar to flash, it might require a lot more than what I was looking to put into the script.